# The c++ programming language by Bjarne Stroustrup - operator new

Tags: c++, new-operator, placement-new

Section "11.2.4 Overloading new" ends with:

> "There is no special syntax for placement of arrays. Nor need there be since arbitrary types can be allocated by placement new. However, an operator delete can be defined for arrays".

If I understand it correctly, what is being said is that for arrays, we use the usual **placement new** syntax, which would invoke the appropriate operator `new[]`. But, what I don't understand is the last sentence. What is he trying to say there? Afaik, we can specify both `operator new` and `operator delete` for arrays.

Comment: Section 11.2.4 of ...

Comment: @YvesDaoust I suspect OP is referring to section 11.2.4 of "The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup

Comment: @0x5453, yes, that's correct! I will update the title

Comment: Yes, I suppose by the last sentence, he was indicating the operations indicated by the keyword `delete`.

Comment: @DDG could you update the title so that it contains information about the question being asked? That way, other people with the same query can easily find it. THanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special allocator for arrays (`operator new[]()`) but it is not dependent on a special syntax.

In the following code

```
new T();
```

or

```
new (p) T();
```

The compiler will generate a call to either `operator new(...)` or `operator new[](...)` depending on whether `T` is an array type.  There is no syntactic difference in the *new-expression*.

(Now, there is a special syntax for a *new-expression* with a runtime size... but invocation of `operator new[]()` is not limited to scenarios with a runtime size)

---

In contrast to `new`, for `delete` the same pointer type is compatible with both scalar and array.  So you the programmer must tell the compiler which you want via

```
delete p;
```

vs

```
delete [] p;
```

There is no automatic translation to `delete[]` based on recognition of an array type.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Voigt! But what you mentioned is how new operator works for arrays and scalar types. My question is with regards to the last sentence in the book. It says "However, an operator delete can be defined for arrays". Why highlight operator delete only? We can define operator new. Placement new operator can be called by placement new syntax, however there is no placement delete syntax, so mentioning about operator new did not make sense to me.

Comment: @DDG There is a placement deallocation function (`operator delete(void* p, placement args)`).  It is only used if an exception is thrown during placement new (while running the single constructor if a scalar / any element constructor if an array).  Once any new-expression executes successfully, the compiler no longer has the placement arguments so a delete-expression wouldn't be passing them to the deallocation function..